# Unable to set variables value in html using Python-Flask - Values converted to encoded format

Tags: python, jinja2

Trying to create line chart using Python-Flask and Chart.js.

I can see the chart when I hard code the values directly in the html file. But If I parse value from my code to html, values are converted in some encoding format. Not sure how to handle this.

My Code :

```
from flask import Flask, Markup, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

labels = [
       'WEEK1', 'WEEK2', 'WEEK3', 'WEEK4'
]

values = [{'pointColor': 'rgba(0,128,0)', 'strokeColor': 'rgba(0,128,0)', 'data': [49.29, 64.3, 99.07, 97], 'fillColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'label': 'Green'}, {'pointColor': 'rgba(220,180,0,1)', 'strokeColor': 'rgba(255,153,0)', 'data': [94.3, 90.9, 91.9, 92.1], 'fillColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'label': 'Orange'}, {'pointColor': 'rgba(0,0,255)', 'strokeColor': 'rgba(0,0,255)', 'data': [74.3, 60.9, 81.9, 72.1], 'fillColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'label': 'Blue'}, {'pointColor': 'rgba(128,0,128)', 'strokeColor': 'rgba(128,0,128)', 'data': [54.3, 50.9, 51.9, 52.1], 'fillColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'label': 'Purple'}]

colors = [
    "#C71585", "#FF4500", "#FEDCBA", "#46BFBD"]

@app.route('/line')
def line():
    line_labels=labels
    line_values=values
    return render_template('line_chart.html', title='Line', max=100, labels=line_labels, values=line_values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

HTML file : [If I substitute the values for "labels & datasets" directly in the html file itself. it works]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>{{ title }}</title>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<center>
{{ values }}
<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<script>

var demoData = {
    labels : {{ labels }}
    datasets : {{ values }}
  }

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(demoData);
</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Error message in the browser (seems values are in encoded format. hence its unable to parse) :

[image]

Someone please help me to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax` with `jquery` to dynamically retrieve the `json`ified data values from the backend and utilize the results to power the graph.

In your Python application, add an additional route to receive the `ajax` request and return the `json`ified results:

```
from flask import Flask, Markup, render_template, jsonify
import json

labels = ['WEEK1', 'WEEK2', 'WEEK3', 'WEEK4']
values = [{'pointColor': 'rgba(0,128,0)', 'strokeColor': 'rgba(0,128,0)', 'data': [49.29, 64.3, 99.07, 97], 'fillColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'label': 'Green'}, {'pointColor': 'rgba(220,180,0,1)', 'strokeColor': 'rgba(255,153,0)', 'data': [94.3, 90.9, 91.9, 92.1], 'fillColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'label': 'Orange'}, {'pointColor': 'rgba(0,0,255)', 'strokeColor': 'rgba(0,0,255)', 'data': [74.3, 60.9, 81.9, 72.1], 'fillColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'label': 'Blue'}, {'pointColor': 'rgba(128,0,128)', 'strokeColor': 'rgba(128,0,128)', 'data': [54.3, 50.9, 51.9, 52.1], 'fillColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'label': 'Purple'}]
colors = ['#C71585', '#FF4500', '#FEDCBA', '#46BFBD']

@app.route('/get_data')
def get_data():
   return flask.jsonify({'labels':json.dumps(labels), 'values':json.dumps(values), 'colors':json.dumps(colors), 'max':100})

@app.route('/line')
def line():
  line_labels=labels
  line_values=values
  return render_template('line_chart.html', title='line')
```

Now, in your template, utilize `ajax` to retrieve the values from `/get_data`:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
   <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js'></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
  <center>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script>
   var values;
   var labels;
   $.ajax({
    url: "/get_data",
    type: "get",
    data: {'key': 'ignore'}, //can send data from frontend to backend if needed
    success: function(response) {
      $(response.values).insertBefore("#myChart");
      values = response.values;
      labels = response.labels;
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
       //pass
     }
   });
   var demoData = {
     labels : labels,
     datasets : values
   }

   var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
   var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(demoData);
  </script>
 </center>
 </body>
</html>
```